# Unexpected Trait Behavior

Tags: scala, traits

Given a simple Algebraic Data Type of `Parent`:

```
scala> sealed trait Parent
defined trait Parent

scala> case object Boy extends Parent
defined object Boy

scala> case object Girl extends Parent
defined object Girl
```

I defined a trait:

```
scala> trait HasGirl { 
     |   val x: Girl.type
     | }
defined trait HasGirl
```

Then, I created a case class that implemented `HasGirl`, but provided an `x` value of `Boy.type`.

```
scala> case class Thing(x: Boy.type) extends HasGirl
defined class Thing
```

I had expected a compile-time error, since I don't see how an `x` of type `Boy.type` conforms to `val x: Girl.type`.

What's going on here?

Comment: Is the `x` in `Thing` related to the `x` in the trait?

Comment: Well, `Thing` extends `HasGirl`. Since the latter expects an `x` of type `Girl.type`, I *believe* that `Thing`'s `x: Boy.type` maps to `HasGirl`'s `x`.

Comment: Indeed, `Thing(Boy).asInstanceOf[HasGirl].x` produces `java.lang.ClassCastException: Boy$ cannot be cast to Girl$`. Interesting.

Comment: Or just `val t: HasGirl = Thing(Boy); println(t.x)` (without an explicit cast, which is what `asInstanceOf` is) also produces a `ClassCastException`. Looks like a Scala bug.

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9574

Answer (score 1):

It seems that singleton types without members are type-equivalent somehow here. Perhaps it's a bug (you filed a ticket). For example, the following produces a runtime-error:

```
sealed trait Parent
case object Boy  extends Parent
case object Girl extends Parent

trait HasGirl {
  val x: Girl.type
}

case class Thing(x: Boy.type) extends HasGirl {
  def y: Girl.type = (this: HasGirl).x
}


val t = Thing(Boy)
t.y   // ClassCastException !
```

If I add a member, you get a compile-time error:

```
sealed trait Parent
case object Boy  extends Parent
case object Girl extends Parent { def hello = 1234 }

trait HasGirl {
  val x: Girl.type
}

case class Thing(x: Boy.type) extends HasGirl
```

> ```
> <console>:57: error: overriding value x in trait HasGirl of type Girl.type;
>  value x has incompatible type
>        case class Thing(x: Boy.type) extends HasGirl
>                         ^
> ```