# How to concretely set abstract type with type bound?

Tags: scala, types

I am trying to use case objects' types as abstract types. I was surprised to see (similar) code below compiles:

```
sealed abstract class Bar

case object BarOne extends Bar

case object BarTwo extends Bar

sealed abstract class Foo {
  type A <: Bar

  def f: A
}

object Foo {
  object FooOne extends Foo {
    type A = BarOne.type
    val f = BarTwo
  }

  object FooTwo extends Foo {
    type A = BarTwo.type
    val f = BarOne
  }
}
```

In my real example `Foo` is parametrized and used as a case class. So I can't just make `A` a type parameter.

How does `f = BarTwo` compile, when `A` is set to be `BarOne.type`?

If `A` in `f: A` is interpreted as `A <: Bar`, why is that so?

Is there a way to concretely set `A` for each object instance of `Foo`?

---

I am using Scala 2.11.8.

---

**Update:** when I replace `val attributeType = ...` with `def attributeType = ...` in `FooOne` & `FooTwo` compilation fails (as expected).

Comment: Is the missing `extends Foo` on `FooOne` and `FooTwo` a typo? Because it doesn't compile if you add that.

Comment: @EndeNeu It was an oversight. And you are right, it doesn't compile (as expected). I have updated the question to make it look as close as possible to the real code. Of course it's no use since the code above doesn't compile and my code compiles.

Comment: @muhuk if the code above doesn't compile then it doesn't represent your compiling code. This question isn't answerable unless you get a correct minimal example.

Comment: ok. Now the code above *does compile* and it shouldn't compile to my understanding.

Comment: This has to be a bug.

Comment: @Martijn there are bugs and also limitations. For instance, dotty fixes limitations around constraints on abstract members. There's also a ticket about how the type of an overriding member is inferred (from RHS vs from the overridden type).

Comment: @som-snytt does this "bug" also exist when one uses Type Parameters instead of a type declaration? I tend to prefer Type Parameters.

Comment: @Martijn robot1208 's example now errors. And see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has anyone suggested you upgrade to a modern version of Scala? (Joke.)

The error about the override gives a nice path for the type.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0-M5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sealed abstract class Bar

case object BarOne extends Bar

case object BarTwo extends Bar

sealed abstract class Foo {
  type A <: Bar

  def f: A
}

object Foo {
  object FooOne extends Foo {
    type A = BarOne.type
    val f = BarTwo
  }

  object FooTwo extends Foo {
    type A = BarTwo.type
    val f = BarOne
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:26: error: overriding method f in class Foo of type => Foo.FooOne.A;
 value f has incompatible type
           val f = BarTwo
               ^
<console>:31: error: overriding method f in class Foo of type => Foo.FooTwo.A;
 value f has incompatible type
           val f = BarOne
               ^
```

The bug was [this one](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9574), and the duplicate question is [from last November](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33974428/1296806).

The nature of the bug was also clever: it was introduced by `-Yoverride-objects`, which is not a very useful option but figures in a couple of my S.O. answers, and now in a question.

Edit:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> object X ; object Y
defined object X
defined object Y

scala> class C { def f: X.type = X }
defined class C

scala> class D extends C { override def f: Y.type = Y }
defined class D

scala> :quit
$ scalam
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0-M5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> scala> object X ; object Y

// Detected repl transcript. Paste more, or ctrl-D to finish.

defined object X
defined object Y

scala> class C { def f: X.type = X }
defined class C

scala> class D extends C { override def f: Y.type = Y }
defined class D
// Replaying 3 commands from transcript.

scala> object X ; object Y
defined object X
defined object Y

scala> class C { def f: X.type = X }
defined class C

scala> class D extends C { override def f: Y.type = Y }
<console>:13: error: overriding method f in class C of type => X.type;
 method f has incompatible type
       class D extends C { override def f: Y.type = Y }
                                        ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know what is going on here, but I did get the problem a bit more isolated. Also, it works with Foo subclasses as well as objects.  I've confirmed this compiles on scalac 2.11.8:

```
object BarOne
object BarTwo

abstract class Foo[A] {
  def attributeType: A
}

object FooContainer {
  class FooOne extends Foo[BarOne.type] {
    val attributeType = BarTwo
  }

  object FooTwo extends Foo[BarOne.type] {
    val attributeType = BarOne
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know how to get a large code fragment on Stack Overflow otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

1. A in f: A is interpreted as A <: Bar
2. Because that is what A represents when F is defined in abstract class
3. How about overriding the abstract definition (the below won't compile):

   ```
   object Foo {

     object FooOne extends Foo {
       type A = BarOne.type
       override val f: A = BarTwo
     }

     object FooTwo extends Foo {
       type A = BarTwo.type
       override val f: A = BarOne
     }

   }
   ```